# Unreasonably high current draw

Tags: sensor, current-measurement, accelerometer

With the [MMA8452](http://www.freescale.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA8452Q.pdf), it claims that it draws 44uA when ODR = 100Hz in Normal Mode.

However, I'm measuring 1.5mA when ODR = 100Hz. Does anyone know how this could be the case? In Low Power Mode, I'm getting almost identical values. I get even higher values in High Resolution mode.

I'm using a 100R shunt and I'm getting the same values with a scope and with a DMM. I'm using a [GY-45](http://nl.aliexpress.com/store/product/10pcs-lot-GY-45-MMA8452-Modules-Digital-Triaxial-Accelerometer-High-precision-Inclination-Module-Free-Shipping/606998_1319594140.html?storeId=606998), but the I2C pull-ups wouldn't draw that much more current - right?

Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

Here's the circuit for GY-45

[image]

I'm tried powering it by using the VCC_IN power line with 3.3V and VCC_3.3V with 3.3V. Same measurements.

I did some more measurements. The Vds across the NFETs are around 0.12V. The voltage across the two left 4.7K are around 0.08V and the voltage across the two right 4.7K are around 0.02V. Do these figure help an explanation?

**UPDATE 2:**

I've desoldered the LDO and have supplied 3.3V and 5V to Vin, but same measurements.

Comment: Circuit diagram?

Comment: What's all the other stuff on that module? And without knowing how everything is connected it's hard to tell what might be wrong.

Comment: Sure. I've updated my question with the circuit.

Comment: Unfortunately it's on the module. I've tried powering it through `VCC_IN` and through `VCC_3.3V` - same measurements though.

Comment: if SDA and/or SCL are held low for whatever reason that 2mA is reasonable.

Comment: When ODR=100Hz, both SDA and SCL are at 3.3V.

Comment: Electric scheme would help. My guess is you have contention on outputs. Only outputs i can see are interrupts and SDA. Try disconnecting interrupts and check if I2C is properly configured.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I haven't got interrupts hooked up. Just I2C. I'm getting good measurements, but it's the current draw that seems wonky.

Comment: Is it possible that your grounds are not connected well? Maybe something else draws your current?

Comment: @GregoryKornblum I think my ground is OK. I'm getting pretty clean 3.3V across.

Comment: I did some more measurements. The Vds across the NFETs are around 0.12V. The voltage across the two left 4.7K are around 0.08V and the voltage across the two right 4.7K are around 0.02V. Do these figure help an explanation?

Comment: I assume you're measuring just between Vcc3.3 and your device?

Comment: I mean, you're not including anything like he I2C bus in your measurement, right?

Comment: Have you looked in the datasheet of the voltage converter? Where do you exactly measure the current? Before or after the regulator? For proper work a regulator normally needs some current. Measure one time before and after.

Comment: Well, because it's a module, I could only measure the current going into the module. So that includes the I2C bus.

Comment: I've desoldered the LDO and have supplied 3.3V and 5V to Vin, but same measurements.

Comment: I think i know. It's the pull ups :) 3.3V/2.35kR=1.4mA

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I think it's a coincidence. I've measured the voltages across the pull-ups - they're only 0.08V.

Comment: Replace them with 10k

Comment: OP doesn't say what speed I2C is running at, but 10k is usually way too big a pull-up for I2C. The rise times will be most of the lock period.

Comment: I think you are confused. It depends on trace capacitance, but usually 10k works well. Anyway, it definitely worth trying.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum  It depends on both: speed and bus capacitance of I2C.

Comment: I assume the current measurement is between Vcc and the chip's VDD pin.  The pullups shouldn't be included -- as the data sheet doesn't talk about how much current the BUS needs.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29820/discussion-on-question-by-john-munroe-unreasonably-high-current-draw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "MMA8452" may be out of spec or faulty.

[What to expect buying cheap electronic components from eBay](https://edwardmallon.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/what-to-expect-when-buying-cheap-electronic-components/)

> one thing I have found to be particularly diagnostic is how much
>   current an IC draws... I have run into several cheap sensors that give
>   decent readings, but *never* go into low current sleep modes.

Answer (score 0):

Current seems specced at Vdd=2.5 V.  I suppose using 3.3V can increase your current draw, but I would hope not as much as you're seeing.

Comment: I've tried Vdd=2.3V and Vdd=2.5V; I get 1.1mA at 100Hz, which is still orders of magnitude off.